# What's is the best and common way of adding a grid to a Cocos2D game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, grid

I need to add a grid to the background of a game. It should be both zoomable and I should be able to know at which square I am drawing another object now. I need something like this:[image: Grid]

What's the most common and proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tileMap(CCTMXTiledMap) inside CCLayerPanZoom. Its easy to track grid clicked and easy to zoom.

Comment: Great answer! Would you create a 'grid-layer' in Tiled to achieve this?

Comment: @Eyeball, I used tileMaps